# Organizing populating a multidimensional array with dynamic scape data - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, curl, multidimensional-array, web-scraping

**Introduction**
I'm attempting to scrape a particular site for it's headlines and the links associated. Then scrape the linked pages for article text. I am using cURL and [simple_html_dom.php](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/).

**Problem**
I'm trying to arrange all of this data; headline, link and article text, in a multidimensional array with the following structure:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => title 1
            [1] => link 1
            [2] => text 1
        )       
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => title 2
            [1] => link 2
            [2] => text 2
        )   
)
```

But no matter how I try to accomplish this, the structure is completely wrong and incorrect. How can I save the corresponding text with it's link and title?

**Code**

```
<?php
$results_page = curl($url); // Downloading the results page using curl() funtion
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load($results_page);
$items = $html->find('h2[class=artTitle]');  // Exploding each h2
foreach($items as $post) {
    $headlines[] = array($post->children(0)->innertext); // Saving h2 text
    $url_results[] = ($post->children(0)->href); // Saving h2 link
}
foreach($url_results as $url_result) { 
    $results_page = curl($url_result);
    $html->load($results_page);
    foreach($html->find('#articleText p[!class]') as $post) // Finding all p elements inside container
        $articles[] = array($post->plaintext); // Adding p elements to array
}
?>
```

I have excluded my cURL function as I don't see it as a factor in this problem and don't want to clutter the question. I will of course add it, if need be.

The following are my current array structures:

**Current array structure of $headlines:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Headline 1¨
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Headline 2¨
        )
)
```

**Current array structure of $url_results:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Link 1
    [1] => Link 2
)
Array
```

**Current array structure of $articles:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Paragraph 1 Text 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Paragraph 2 Text 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Paragraph 1 Text 2
        )
)
```

Comment: I see your intended output in your example but I don't see the current output. Can you provide that as well?

Comment: Array structures have now been added, thank you for reminding me.

Answer (score 0):

How about declaring an index in the first foreach loop and using that to determine the placement of subarray(s).  This way you can nest your subsequent foreach loops and continue with the array build.

```
foreach($items as $index=>$post) {
    $desired_array[$index][0]=$post->children(0)->innertext; // Saving h2 text
    $url_results=$post->children(0)->href; // Saving h2 link
    foreach($url_results as $url_result) { 
        $results_page=curl($url_result);
        $html->load($results_page);
        foreach($html->find('#articleText p[!class]') as $post) // Finding all p elements inside container
            $desired_array[$index][1]=""; //I don't know where $link comes from
            $desired_array[$index][2]=array($post->plaintext);
        }
    }
}
```

I was unable to test this because I don't have a sample `$items` to work with.

Comment: @user2304993  If this sufficiently solves your problem please award me the green tick (and possibly an upvote for being helpful).  Otherwise, please provide a sample `$item` and explain what issues remain.